# What do I do to make this socket to a websocket?

Tags: python, sockets, websocket

I've got this code at the moment, it's a simple socket server:

```
import socket
import time

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostname()

port = 9999

serversocket.bind((host, port))

serversocket.listen(5)
while True:
    clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()

    print(str(addr) + "connected")
    test = "Package"
    clientsocket.send(test.encode('utf-8'))
    clientsocket.close()
```

I also made a client that gets the message. However, how do I make it so that when I type in the address of my socket on for example Chrome, it displays "Package". I have basic knowledge on handlers and such, but I can't find any DIY websocket tutorials on the internet.

- I do not want to use for example tornado, I want to make a simple one myself

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: This question is way too broad, if you want to implement websocket yourself, go read the specs, it's all described in there.

Comment: @LieRyan 'in there'. My question is not way too broad. I'm just asking how I can make a basic websocket that displays a word on a webbrowser... I don't need hard code, I just need referrals

Comment: does Google [break for you](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+socket+specification&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)?